# how to message to a specific mobile number using node.js?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm new to node.js. Thinking of to implement a system which will send a text to a given number. Please help me. Thank You.

Comment: well what have you tried? its kind of difficult for this to be implemented if basic knowledge of node.js doesn't exist and even how the whole thing works, texting from a pc

Answer (score 2):

To send SMS messages from Node.js, give Twilio a try: http://www.twilio.com/docs/node/install

```
// Your accountSid and authToken from twilio.com/user/account
var accountSid = 'AC32a3c49700934481addd5ce1659f04d2';
var authToken = "";
var client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);

client.sms.messages.create({
    body: "Jenny please?! I love you <3",
    to: "+14159352345",
    from: "+14158141829"
}, function(err, message) {
    process.stdout.write(message.sid);
});
```